# App crashes while using NSURL URLWithString in a "for" loop

Tags: ios, xcode, for-loop, nsurl

Here's my code,

```
for (int i=0; i<=[selfLinksArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *temp = selfLinksArray[i];
    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:temp ];
    NSLog(@"NSURL:%@",tempURL);
    NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tempData options:0 error:&error];
    NSDictionary *volumeInfoDict = [tempDict objectForKey:@"volumeInfo"];
    titleArray[i]=[volumeInfoDict objectForKey:@"title"];        
}
```

Xcode shows me this error

```
[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf334f0bc0
2016-01-19 16:12:34.937 BookFindr[7775:449799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf334f0bc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f34be65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010edc4deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f35448d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2a190a ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2a14b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f32e261 _CFURLCreateWithURLString + 81
6   Foundation                          0x000000010e97a465 -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithString:relativeToURL:] + 349
7   Foundation                          0x000000010e97a2e2 +[NSURL(NSURL) URLWithString:relativeToURL:] + 59
8   BookFindr                           0x000000010e8bf9ab -[tabResTableViewController viewDidLoad] + 219
9   UIKit                               0x000000010f88ef98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
10  UIKit                               0x000000010f894f4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
11  UIKit                               0x000000010f8c4e44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
12  UIKit                               0x000000010f8d523f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
13  UIKit                               0x000000010f8d63af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
14  UIKit                               0x000000010fa7cff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
15  UIKit                               0x000000010f7af4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000011327b59a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000011326fe70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000011326fcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113264475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113291c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
21  UIKit                               0x000000010f6f2f7c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7329
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f277a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f26d95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f26ce13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f26c828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112b08ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
27  UIKit                               0x000000010f6f8610 UIApplicationMain + 171
28  BookFindr                           0x000000010e8c101f main + 111
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111a8792d start + 1
30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have imported selfLinkArray from another viewController. I want to fetch various titles which are present in VolumeInfo dictionary. This dictionary is present in each individual link in selfLinksArray. Please help me with this error. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are not getting a string like you expect at some point. You are getting an array as an element within the loop. Set an exception break point to stop at the offending line and you can inspect the cause from there.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze your error and your backtrace :

> -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf334f0bc0'

The issue is written here: the `length` method is called on an `NSArray` object.
Wait, this method is not even written in this sample! Don't worry, let's analyze it.

> 6   Foundation                          0x000000010e97a465
>   -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithString:relativeToURL:] + 349
>
> 7   Foundation                          0x000000010e97a2e2 +[NSURL(NSURL) URLWithString:relativeToURL:]

The crash log indicates that the crash occurs when you try to init the `NSURL` object. The only parameter of this init method is a `NSString` object. But are we sure that `temp` is really a `NSString` object ?

This variable is casted without checking if it's really an `NSString` object. It can be anthing, for example... the `NSArray` which receive a call to the `length` method. Also, this method is existing for a `NSString` object, so the `unrecognizer selector` error look totally related.

Where do you we call `length` on this `NSString` object ? My guess is, according to the backtrace, that `URLWithString:` call this method to check the `NSString` length in order to initialize properly the `NSURL` object.